# jQuery: Cannot select val='' from generated dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following JS for generating a dropdown list for provinces/states:

```
var populateList = function (list, element) {
    element.append("<option val=''>Select...</option>")
    list.forEach(function (val) {
        element.append("<option val=" + val[0] + ">" + val[1] + "</option>");
    })
}

var canProvinces = [
    ['ON', 'Ontario'],
    ['QC', 'Quebec'],
    ['NS', 'Nova Scotia'],
    ['NB', 'New Brunswick'],
    ['MB', 'Manitoba'],
    ['BC', 'British Columbia'],
    ['PE', 'Prince Edward Island'],
    ['SK', 'Saskatchewan'],
    ['AB', 'Alberta'],
    ['NL', 'Newfoundland and Labrador'],
    ['NT', 'Northwest Territories'],
    ['YT', 'Yukon'],
    ['NU', 'Nunavut']];
```

The idea I'm working towards is when the user switches countries in a form, the system can use `populateList()` to switch to a new list whenever the user switches countries. Then I use jQuery to put the province abbreviation in a hidden input field. Here is the code in the form:

```
<script src="list-of-provices/states-from-above.js"></script>

<input id="UserCountry" value="CA" type="text" /> <!-- to be converted to dropdown when issue resolves -->

<select id="province-select" name="province-select"></select>

<input id="Province" type="hidden"/>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

   if ($('#UserCountry').val() == 'CA') {
            populateList(canProvinces, $("#province-select"));
        } else if ($('#UserCountry').val() == 'US') {
            populateList(usaStates, $("#province-select"));
        }

    $('#province-select').bind('input propertychange', function () {

           //something wrong here? Returns full name, not 2 letter abbreviation.
           console.log($("#province-select").val())

           $('#Province').val($("#province-select").val())
        })
});
</script>
```

I haven't got to the Country switching part yet because, despite everything I've tried, `$("#province-select").val()` returns the Text from the dropdown, not the value. I have not been able to find a reason for this. Here is the HTML generated by the code:

```
<select id="province-select" name="province-select">
   <option val="">Select...</option>
   <option val="ON">Ontario</option>
   <option val="QC">Quebec</option>
   <option val="NS">Nova Scotia</option>
   <option val="NB">New Brunswick</option>
   <option val="MB">Manitoba</option>
   <option val="BC">British Columbia</option>
   <option val="PE">Prince Edward Island</option>
   <option val="SK">Saskatchewan</option>
   <option val="AB">Alberta</option>
   <option val="NL">Newfoundland and Labrador</option>
   <option val="NT">Northwest Territories</option>
   <option val="YT">Yukon</option>
   <option val="NU">Nunavut</option>
</select>
```

Is there something I am missing? `$("#province-select").val()` should return the val="" from the dropdown, but for me it returns the text.

Any thoughts?

Comment: `.bind()` is deprecated, you should use `.on()`.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: More detail please? I was under the impression that .on() / .bind() was the event listener.

Comment: Typo: `val=` should be `value=`

Comment: It is. But `if ($('#UserCountry').val() == 'CA')` is not in the `.bind()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a small mistake in your code. The attribute to be used for setting the value of option is `value` and not `val`. Replace your

```
element.append("<option val=" + val[0] + ">" + val[1] + "</option>");
```

with

```
element.append("<option value='" + val[0] + "'>" + val[1] + "</option>");
```

and you are good.

Comment: Don't post a real answer for simple typos. Just vote to close.

Comment: Also, value need to be wrapped with single quote (`'`) or double quote (`"`) as value seems to be `string`.

Comment: @Barmar Sure, but I don't think it's a typo. Somehow the OP was convinced that `val` is the right attribute to be used. Probably, `jQuery` is the reason. Also, I saw your comment after posting my answer, if not I wouldn't have answered

Comment: @Karan - Thanks for pointing it out. I have edited the answer although I think it should work fine as long as there is no space in the value.

Comment: It's still such a minor error, and no one else is going to make this mistake. The question serves no purpose for posterity.

Comment: jQuery using val instead of value tripped me up. If you want to wipe this question off the map, I am okay with that.